# Math paper translation

Tags: bayesian, translation-request

Does anybody know if Bruno de Finetti's paper, Sul significato soggettivo della probabilità, has been translated into English?  I am teaching myself Italian, but for some reason de Finetti doesn't mention a boy eating an apple or a woman reading a book or any of the other phrases I know yet. ;-)

The citation would be:

> de Finetti (1931), "Sul significato soggettivo della probabilità", Fundamenta Mathematicæ, 17, pp 298 – 329

Comment: a chapter in https://www.google.com/books/edition/Foundations_of_Bayesianism/j33vCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=de+Finetti+(1931),+%22Sul+significato+soggettivo+della+probabilit%C3%A0&pg=PA173&printsec=frontcover